# How do i animate a curve(String) for a bow with a soft-body physics type

Tags: animation

I'm new to blender so i would love some help with how i can animate this bow string correctly. Currently i have gotten the string to pull back, but the endpoints seem to pull off the tips of the bow. I've been trying to fix this for ages longer than i think it should be taking. So if someone wants to help me fix this or completely correct what i have done that would be greatly appreciated.

Also here's a visual representation:[image: sorry the renders are not colored!! frame 1]

[image: frame 12]

[image: frame 27]

Comment: This might help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131773/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-paths-working-on-a-string-for-longbow/132733#132733

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out!!!